# Discord bot accepting reaction to message

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm still learning the [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library so I apologize for any rookie mistakes.

The code below is part of a function which performs 3 actions:

1. Connect to an `sqlite3` database
2. Ask what kitname to create and insert the new kitname into the `sqlite3` database
3. Ask if the user would like to add cards to their kitname.

````py
 #To create a new kit
@client.command(name="createkit")
async def createkit(message):
    author = message.author
    await author.send("What name would you like to give the new kit?")
    msg = await client.wait_for('message')
    kitName = msg.content #name of kit user wants to make
    userID = msg.author.id #User ID of the author of the reply message
    userName = msg.author.name #Username of the author who wrote the reply message
    db = sqlite3.connect('kits.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kits(
    DeckID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    User TEXT NOT NULL,
    UserID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Deckname TEXT NOT NULL
    )
    ''')
    print("Connected to Kits")
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM kits WHERE UserID = {userID}")
    sql = ("INSERT INTO kits(User, UserID, Deckname) VALUES(?,?,?)")
    val = (userName, userID, kitName)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    db.commit()
    await author.send(f"{kitName} has been created!")
    addCards = await author.send(f"Would you like to add cards to {kitName}?")
    await addCards.add_reaction('')
    await addCards.add_reaction('')
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')
    if user == client.user:
        return
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == '':
        print(user)
        await user.send('Great!') #<-- error
        print("Replied with thumbs up!")
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == '':
        await user.send('Too bad...') #<-- error
        print("Replied with thumbs down!")
    cursor.close()
    db.close()```
````

Parts 1 and 2 work without any issues. Part 3 which asks users to react with a thumbs up or thumbs down emoji throws the error below:

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: 
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 
'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'send'
```

The weird thing with this is I will restart the bot and go through the command use. I will react with the thumbs up emoji, and it will reply with "Great!" without producing any errors. I will run through it a second time and reply with a either a thumbs down or thumbs up, and the above error occurs. It seems to work for the first time, but then the second time it errors out. Even if I restart the bot shortly after, it will fail. If I wait a while before restarting then try again, the bot will work once, then fail every time after that with the same problem. I am not sure what the issue is. I have looked over some other threads that seem to address the problem to no avail.

Any help in advance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try printing out the `user` object after `wait_for` and see what type it is. Maybe it is not always the same type, as the error said, `ClientUser` objects don't have a `send` method

Comment: @HymnsForDisco It looks like it is printing the bot as user, which would explain why it can't send, I think... I added ```if user == client.user: return``` before the ```elif str(reaction.emoji)...``` lines and I still get the same problem. It worked once, then failed for attempts after. Maybe a check? I'm entirely foreign to those.

Comment: Please include the entire function.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Edited to show that entire function. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your error is that the bot is trying to DM itself.

Discord.py's `wait_for` function accepts a [check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) kwarg that allows you to filter for a specific event.  If you do not include this check then the library will wait till the next event of that type (in this case a reaction_add) from anywhere. In your specific case it happends to be the bot adding the reaction:

```
await addCards.add_reaction('')
await addCards.add_reaction('')
```

A Simple fix for this is to write a check function that will only return `True` if someone else adds that reaction:

```
def check(reaction,user):
    return not user.bot and reaction.message.id == addCards.id and str(reaction.emoji) in ['','']

reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add',check=check)
```

Comment: Awesome! That was about what I expected the problem to be. I wasn't quite familiar with checks yet. Good a time as any to learn. Thanks!